# android studio: handle the messages in the instant messaging app

Tags: android

All the message which is sent by the users should store in database??? if so, how can i store huge amount of message in the db?? insert all message as string to database??

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate record for each message. It gives you better searching and further easy improvement in operation in future.
Thanks

Comment: each message separately store as string in database???  is that what u mean???       how should i design the table in database?